# accusative array value in if statement php

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

I have the weirdest blackout.
but why i am getting 'no' as output and not 'yes'

```
 $test =array ('title' => 'user', 'name'=>'dave','id'=>'4');

        if($test['title']  == 'user'){
          echo 'yes';
        }else{
          echo 'no';
        }

**thanks for the help. apparently the problem was that the real value is link tag. but i used print_r and not var_dump so i missed it **
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce with edited code.

Comment: @Doron Davidowitz This code above is now working. Can you specify what is not working for you? Also please provide: `var_dump($test)`.

Comment: the var_dump showed me it was a link- so 'user' was wrong

Comment: @DoronDavidowitz Uhm can you just copy & paste the result here? Otherwise we cannot help you.

Comment: It obviously works: https://3v4l.org/WA3NV. You must be missing something.

Comment: @DoronDavidowitz If my solution had helped you please mark it as "accepted" otherwise provide feedback please.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `$test['title']` refers to the value associated with the `key` 'title' of your `array` and the value is 'user' in your case. You can just change the `if-statement` to:

```
if ($test['title'] == 'user') { ... }
```

Your array looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [title] => user
    [name] => dave
    [id] => 4
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($test['title']  == 'user'){
```

it works if you do.

Comment: sorry, i have edit it and forgot to change the if statement itself. (i edited it)
but is i know it should work but its not